Google Refresh token expires
I would get generate a refresh token that should expires after 7 days, it expires the next day
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
"expires_in": 3599,
"token_type": "Bearer"
Not sure whats going on
Expecting that it doesn't expire before 7 days.
